# Nodemailer Error occurred: Connection timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel, nodemailer

I'm using node mailer to send email. Here is the code I use:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'email',
            pass: 'password',
        },
        secureConnection: false,
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        },
    });
```

locally it works, but once it's deployed to vercel servers it throws error

Error occurred: Connection timeout

How this could be fixed?

I tried multiple versions of createTransport and nothing works. Is this firewall issue and if so who should I contact ?

Comment: Have you checked Vercel's [runtime logs](https://vercel.com/docs/observability/runtime-logs) ?

Comment: Yes, it says Error occurred: Connection timeout . 

I tried port 587 with secure false, but also no luck. What's wrong on vercel side ? I have it working locally thought.

Comment: And also sometimes get Error occurred: Greeting never received

and then connection closed unexpectedly. Do you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: Check which [plan](https://vercel.com/blog/cron-jobs#included-resources-for-cron-jobs-and-vercel-functions) you are currently in (as the cron job's like node-mailer has execution limits between plans), and also check the timeout [max duration](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/runtimes#max-execution-duration) across plans.